# Web push notification service link

Tags: push-notification, web-push

I have made an angular application that will run in a secured network. This application also shows push notifications upon some operations. But the problem is that this application is showing push notifications when run outside the secured environment and not in the secured environment.

By secured network / environment I mean, there will be checks on the eligible links that a user can open on the secured network. So, I have a doubt that the service, which could be a HTTP link or some other protocol, that is responsible for getting the push notification to the machine and browser from web push servers need to be whitelisted by the administrator. **And I don't know what are those links and ports** and they are not mentioned anywhere (as per my knowledge). **I need those links and ports for chrome, firefox and edge web push service** which could improve this situation.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This is a [complete list of the hosts](https://github.com/pushpad/known-push-services/blob/master/whitelist) that you should whitelist in your firewall in order to send the notifications from your server. I am sure about that because we use that list in production. Maybe the same hosts are used by the browser to retrieve the notifications, but I am not 100% sure about this last point...